# how to create jpg file from given string

Tags: vb.net

I have converted given string to JPG file format. But i need those image string in center. Iam getting output from leftside of rectangle.

```
            Dim stext As String = "Testing"
            Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
            Dim MyRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 800)
            Dim MyGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
            Dim MyImg As Image = New Bitmap(391, 132, MyGraphics)
            Dim imageGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(MyImg)
            imageGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, MyRect)
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
            format.LineAli`enter code here`gnment = StringAlignment.Center
            imageGraphics.DrawString("Testing", New Font("Times New Roman", 30, Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, RectangleF.op_Implicit(MyRect))
            MyGraphics.DrawImage(MyImg, MyRect)
            MyImg.Save(Destfilename & "/"  & "test.jpg")
```

I have given this code output. But i need this string to in **center position**. How to do, Kindly help me through.
Output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7Ka3N0V2NmRnl3UFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example could help you

```
Private Sub CenterTextAt(ByVal gr As Graphics, ByVal txt As _
    String, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    ' Mark the center for debugging.
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Red, x - 10, y, x + 10, y)
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Red, x, y - 10, x, y + 10)

    ' Make a StringFormat object that centers.
    Dim sf As New StringFormat
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    ' Draw the text.
    gr.DrawString(txt, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, x, y, sf)
    sf.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, but what values we should provide on x and y values

Comment: you're wellcome. x e y are the coordinate of the drawn text. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3thd43b(v=vs.110).aspx)